# NHibernate 3 and castle proxy: myList.Contains is broken

Tags: nhibernate, lazy-loading, castle

I'm trying to upgrade a C# .NET 3.5 project from NH 1.2 to NH 3.1. I'm having a hard time with a: `myListOfT.contains(someT)`.

`myListOfT` contains `someT`, and `myListOfT[0]` seems to be `someT` (I can see it with Visual Studio "spy"). HashCodes are the same. `myListOfT[0]` and `someT` are both `Castle.Proxies.T`...

What is wrong with my code and NH 3.1?

---

Let's say that I want to know I some User belongs to a Workplace or a child one's.

```
    public bool UserBelongToWorkplace(Workplace wp, User u)
    {
        if (wp.Users.Contains(u)) return true;

        foreach (Workplace subWp in wp.Workplaces)
        {
            return UserBelongToWorkplace(subWp, u);
        }
    }
```

In this context: `wp.Users : ReadOnlyCollection<User> (hides IList<Users>)`

Nhibernate config:

```
    <property name="cache.use_second_level_cache">true</property>

    <property name="proxyfactory.factory_class">
      NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.ProxyFactoryFactory, NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle
    </property>
```

At runtime, the function always returns `false`, even if the workplace really contains the user.

With debugger/traces I can check that wp.Users[0] == u (same Id, same HashCode). Both objects are proxyfied. It was working fine before the upgrade to Nhibernate 3.1.

I am pretty sure it has something to do with lazy-loading/proxy as we already had kinda issues, but it was involving type comparison (CProxy_User and User for instance).

Comment: I don't understand your issue. What do you expect? What happens? Can you write a stand-alone testcase to reproduce the issue? Can you post some examples?

Comment: Sorry for my late answer. I added some code snippet to my question. I am unable to reproduce it with test case (nothing is proxified in my test context :( ).

Comment: Did you override both Equals and GetHashCode for User? Can you post the code for Workplace and User?

Comment: Thanks Mauricio, that was that: Equals is overriden and makes calls to some foggy framework method that "unproxifies" the type of entities, assuming that the proxy could only be CProxy_XXXX and not Castle.Proxies.XXXProxy.

Comment: Feel free to add an answer so that I could close this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure both `Equals()` and `GetHashCode()` are correctly implemented for `User`